# I and her Vs Her and I

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, articles

1. Mark ordered headphones for XYZ and I.
2. Mark ordered headphones for XYZ and me.

In the above sentences do we need an article before headphones?
I think that in 3 and 4 sentences, sentence 3 is correct. Does the same logic apply in sentence 1 and 2?
2nd sentence feels more right to me.

3. XYZ and I decided to buy a new TV.
4. I and My friend decided to buy a new TV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the traditional rules of English grammar, sentence 1 is wrong and sentence 2 is correct. The case of the two pronouns differs: she/I and her/me are in the same case, but her/I are in different cases.

Nevertheless, you will hear many, perhaps most, native speakers in the US use sentence 1. I still recommend using sentence 2 because at least some will judge sentence 1 to be poor English and because everyone will understand and be comfortable with sentence 2.

In the case of sentences 3 and 4, it is recommended to put the first person last in a list of pronouns. So sentence 3 is what is recommended. That is not, in my opinion, a rule of English grammar, but rather it is considered good manners to mention others before mentioning yourself.

EDIT: Case is just vestigial in English, and so many mistakes of case are not noticed by most native speakers, even by quite a few educated native speakers. Thus, worrying about case is probably not the most important aspect about learning English. If your native language is a Romance or Germanic language, the traditional rules for the case of pronouns in English are quite similar to those in your native language.

EDIT 2: No article is grammatically needed before "headphones." It might be clearer to say "a pair of headphones" because the given structure does not distinguish between a single pair and a truckload of pairs: either is more than one headphone. This is being fussy, however, because it usually would be clear in context.

Comment: I'd quibble with the part about "don't worry about it", I think using proper pronouns is important, but +1 to the rest.

Comment: @ Jay. Yes, I suppose that is how what I said would be interpreted although that is neither what I said nor meant. But thank you. To clarify what I meant is that trying to learn the traditional rules for pronouns is less important than, for example, learning the peculiarities of the structure of English tenses. And furthermore the traditional rules for English are so close to the rules in the Germanic and Romance languages that I know (1 and 3 respectively) that native speakers of those languages likely can just use their native rules. I agree: I personally notice pronouns in the wrong case.

Comment: @Jeff - I bought some clothes for her and me(myself). Can I use the above logic in this situation too?

Comment: @Lea Yes. The same logic applies.